# Overlapping div on navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I need to overlap logo and a cart button on my navigation bar ie.:

[Collapsed navi] [logo] [cart]

However, I cannot seem to get the below code to make them float left, center and right. Hope someone can help. Thank you!

CSS:

```
#navi_container {
  width: 100%;
  }
  
#navi_left {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  }

#navi_right {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  align-content: right;
  }
  
#navi_center {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  align-content: center;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div id='navi_container'>
  <div id='navi_left'>
  <div class='menumobile'/>
  </div>
  <div id='navi_center'>
  <center><a href='url'><img height='auto' src='logoimg.jpg' width='150px'/></a></center>
  </div>
  <div id='navi_right'>
  <span style="float: right;"<a href='url'><img height='auto' src='cartimg.jpg' width='150px'/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If code is HTML,CSS and JavaScript you should add it to JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet, so anyone can run and check visually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `float` you can use `flex` here:

CSS:

```
#navi_container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

You can remove `width` and `float` properties from `#navi_left`, `#navi_right` and `#navi_center`